# if [ $(... | wc -l) = false ] firing regardless of output

Tags: bash, shell

My bash script looks like this. I want to check if a repository exists in git, and if it doesn't then run some additional commands.

```
if [ `git ls-remote --heads $REPOSITORY_PATH $BRANCH | wc -l` = false ]
then
  # Do something if it doesn't exist...
fi
```

But the problem I'm running into is that no matter if the statement in the `if` returns `0` or `1` it always seems to evaluate the statement as true. Is there something I'm missing here? If it returns `0` I want it to run, and if it's `1` I want it to not run.

Comment: The string `false` is not equal to the string `0`. Use `$(git ...| wc -l) -eq 0` instead.

Comment: As an aside, `$( ... )` is strongly preferred in favor to backticks -- see the second table in https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` doesn't have a boolean data type; `false` is just an ordinary string, and your pipe is outputting a literal string `0` (possibly with some whitespace padding, depending on your implementation, not a boolean value.

You need to do an explicit numeric comparison instead:

```
if [ "$(git ls-remote --heads "$REPOSITORY_PATH" "$BRANCH" | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; then
```

(or `-ne`, if you want this to execute when there *is* output).

Comment: or just `if ! git ls-remote ... | grep -q . ; then` to save on processes and capturing output etc.

Comment: That's the same number of processes; you just replaced `wc -l` with `grep`. Syntactically, it is cleaner, since you don't have to capture the output and build a conditional expression, though.

Comment: (At least, depending on how much optimization the shell does with the pipeline in the command substitution.)

Comment: It's only the same number of processes if the shell uses a built-in `[` and doesn't fork for `$(...)`.  Otherwise, yes.

Comment: In bash (tested in v3 and v4), `if [ -z "$(git ls-remote ...)" ]; then` uses just one subprocess (while the `grep` version uses two, and the `wc -l` version uses three).

Comment: @chepner grep stops the execution after the first match. So it is (minimal) more efficient for longer texts.